# VB 2013 Batch Zipping of Listbox Selected Items

Tags: vb.net, foreach, listbox, visual-studio-2013, zip

Looking for more great advice on here. Today I wrote some code that takes a listbox selected item and uses that selection to zip a corresponding file (rename with date and time) and place in one folder and then copy to another. Now I need to be able to iterated through a listbox with many selections so that I can batch zip, rename  and copy. Below is my attempt:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    'Button click events.
    'Start backup.

    Dim PjtPath As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim ZipLocal As String = TextBox2.Text
    Dim ZipNetwk As String = TextBox3.Text

    Static Dim StartPath As String
    Static Dim ZipPath As String

    For Each a As String In ListBox1.SelectedItems()
        Dim PjtName As String = ListBox1.SelectedItems(a).ToString
        Dim ZipExt As String = Format(Now, " yyyy-MM-dd @ HHmm") & ".zip"

        If TextBox2.Text = String.Empty Then
            StartPath = PjtPath & "\" & PjtName
            ZipPath = PjtPath & "\" & PjtName & ZipExt
        ElseIf TextBox2.Text <> String.Empty Then
            StartPath = PjtPath & "\" & PjtName
            ZipPath = ZipLocal & "\" & PjtName & ZipExt
        End If
        System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory _
        (StartPath, ZipPath, IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.Optimal, True)

        If TextBox3.Text <> String.Empty Then
            Dim ZipCopy As String = ZipNetwk & "\" & PjtName & ZipExt
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(ZipPath, ZipCopy)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The error I'm getting is conversion from string to type integer is not valid. Can someone please point me in the right direction. Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim PjtName As String = ListBox1.SelectedItems(a).ToString
```

changed to...

Dim PjtName As String = a

Silly me!

Comment: if you turn on Option Strict, the IDE will catch errors like and tell you what it wrong and where without a runtime error.  There is also a class in IO called Path which will create those path names for you: `thisPath = IO.Path.Compbine(....)`

Comment: I remember you mentionning before. Now turned on. Thanks for all your input!

Comment: If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(ZipPath) Then Goto

Comment: Another quick question. I tried to use the above to skip the zipping and copying in my code if the path already existed in case the user clicked the button again and the zipping was so quick that both new names had the same times appended and so same name. But it doesn't seem to get me anywhere. Do you have a suggestion for this?

Comment: If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(ZipPath) Then Goto, I'm goign to bed ha!

Comment: i'd have to see the current state of the code; just post a new question

Comment: The code worked with the "fileexists" rather than "directory". Another oversight!